# Image out of the JFrame but on the same time on the JFrame

Tags: java

Hey i was wondering if can i make **image out of JFrame** i mean on the border but not icon. I want to make like logo on the left upper corner. Is that possible ? I saw some programs which use .xml but i dont want to use it.

I tried to use

```
setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/assets/logo.png")));
```

with Bounds set

```
setBounds(740, 534, 158, 50);
```

but this is pinned into JFrame not out of it :/

Image size would be like 200x200 px and image for exam-le would be image of ball in .png

Comment: You can put an image in a JFrame, but not on a JFrame.  You'd have to create your own JFrame extension.

Comment: yeee i did it by that way :)